# unwanted margin on absolutely positioned element

Tags: html, css

Why `btnow` has some top margin?

Its css is `top:0`.

```css
.btnowwrap{
 position:relative;
 height:20px;
 background:gold;
}

.btnow{
 position:absolute;
 right:9px;
 top:0;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:19px;
 color:#777;
}
```

```html
<div class='btnowwrap'>
<div class='btnow' id='btnow' title='SADA'>&#x267B;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it because the `height` of icon

Comment: Try adding line-height since you have assigned height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon is in `top:0` this space is because the `height` of icon(see image):

[image]

**Use `line-height: 1em;`**

```css
.btnowwrap{
 position:relative;
 height:20px;
 background:gold;
}

.btnow{
 position:absolute;
 right:9px;
 top:0;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:19px;
 color:#777;
line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class='btnowwrap'>
<div class='btnow' id='btnow' title='SADA'>&#x267B;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: so in this case is there any difference between `line-height: 1em` or `100%` or `19px`?

Comment: line-height: 100% means 100% of the font size for that element, not 100% of its height.

Answer (score 3):

Apply `line-height:100%;`

```css
.btnowwrap{
 position:relative;
 height:20px;
 background:gold;
}

.btnow{
 position:absolute;
 right:9px;
 top:0;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:19px;
 color:#777;
  line-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='btnowwrap'>
<div class='btnow' id='btnow' title='SADA'>&#x267B;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to reduce **font size** then use

**.btnow { line-height: 100% }**

it will fit. You can reduce font size too but line-height is the best solution.